# PHP paypal billing agreement

Tags: php, paypal

This is very general question.
I want my user to sign a Paypal billing agreement with me and bill his PayPal account in the end of the month by usage.
All the code examples I had encountered are using predefined packages, while I need to bill the user by the usage which changed from month to month.

Does anyone knows a PHP code example for this?
Or do you have any link with good How To / code example?

Thanks!

Comment: http://tutorialzine.com/2010/05/donation-center-php-mysql-paypal-api/

That is a good tutorial. But you have to change a bit for your monthly payment.

Comment: thanks, but here the amount of money to charge the user is predefined.

Comment: I know that, but i only knows that tutorial. You have to change a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but it is no use for me, I am looking for a way to charge the user in a different ammount of money in every month.  
In your example I am predefining the ammount of money, I am looking for a way to set it every month.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for your problem? I'm looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

For variable amounts you'll need to use [Reference Transactions](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/) or [Preapproved Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicPreapproval-curl-etc/).

Since you're using PHP I'd recommend taking a look at my [class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/).  It will make this very simple for you, and comes with samples as well as empty templates you just have to fill in.